# Cannot start Hyper-V Host Compute Service

Tags: windows, virtualization, docker, hyper-v, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to install Docker with WSL 2 on my Windows 10 machine. I thought it was fairly simple but two days later I'm still struggling to make it work.

I've tracked the problem from not being able to install a Linux Distribution from the Windows Store. I'm getting an error:

> WslRegisterDistribution failed with error: 0x80370102
> Error: 0x80370102 The virtual machine could not be started because a required feature is not installed.

After some more troubleshooting it is (probably) because I can't run this Hyper-V Host Compute Service:

```
PS C:\Users\jjj> Start-Service "Hyper-V Host Compute Service"

Start-Service : Service 'Hyper-V Host Compute Service (vmcompute)' cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open vmcompute service on computer '.'.
```

In Windows Event Viewer I get this:

> The Hyper-V Host Compute Service service depends on the Windows Container Isolation service which failed to start because of the following error:
> The system cannot find the file specified.

I don't know how to solve this cause I can't find any info online. Is Hyper-V needed for WSL 2 to work?

Things I've done:

1. Enabled SVM Mode in BIOS settings (I was using Virtualbox/Vagrant before so this is enabled already)
2. Enabled the required Windows Features:

[image]

3. Installed Linux kernel update package.
4. Disabled CFG override system settings of vmcompute.exe
5. Ran bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
6. Ran systeminfo but getting `Hyper-V Requirements:      A hypervisor has been detected. Features required for Hyper-V will not be displayed.`

System

> Windows 10 Version 20H2 build 19042.964

I've installed HWiINFO and somehow AMD-V is greyed out so it means it's not supported. But I double checked and SVM Mode IS enabled in BIOS.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the info. Yeah it says that but in BIOS SVM is enabled. I know it's working because since I can't make Docker work I reinstalled VirtualBox and it's working fine.

Comment: The latest, 6.1 since i just reinstalled it today. But it was uninstalled when I was trying  to make this whole thing work. I also had WAMP which has since been removed as well. How can I found out which Hypervisor is running?

Comment: So just finished with everything and still no luck. It did gave me an idea though - I removed Hyper-V and check if  the message "a hypervisor has been detected" is still displaying in systeminfo. And it did! So I think you are right that there is something else running. I started to disable each feature and the message was gone when I disabled "Virtual Machine Platform" I'm guessing this is because it handles vm's in general? What's weird is that if this is removed and Hyper-V is installed, I get the message that a hypervisor is running, but still have the issue.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you may have Ryzen Master installed which, while not 100% clear, in later version it appears due to all the issues caused by Virutalization Based Security and Ryzen Master software may take the liberty of disabling VBS in windows and SVM in the bios.